# ActiveMQ with JMS topic - some messages not dequeued by consumer

Tags: activemq-classic, spring-jms, atomikos, jms-topic

We're trying to set up ActiveMQ 5.9.0 as a message broker using JMS topics, but we're having some issues with the consumption of the messages.

For testing purposes, we have a simple configuration of 1 topic, 1 event producer, and 1 consumer. We send 10 messages one after the other, but every time we run the application, 1-3 of these messages are not consumed! The other messages are consumed and proceesed fine.
We can see that all the messages we're published to the topic in the ActiveMQ managment console, but they never reach the consumer, even if we reastart the application (we can see that the numbers in the "Enqueue" and "Dequeue" columns are different).

EDIT: I should also mention that when using queues instead of topic, this problem does not occur.

Why is this happening? Could it have something to do with atomikos (which is the transaction manger)? Or maybe something else in the configuration? Any ideas/suggestions are welcome. :)

This is the ActiveMQ/JMS spring configuration:

```
    <bean id="connectionFactory" class="com.atomikos.jms.AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean"
    init-method="init" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="uniqueResourceName" value="amq" />
    <property name="xaConnectionFactory">
        <bean class="org.apache.activemq.spring.ActiveMQXAConnectionFactory"
            p:brokerURL="${activemq_url}" />
    </property>
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="10" />
    <property name="localTransactionMode" value="false" />
</bean>

<bean id="cachedConnectionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory">
    <property name="targetConnectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory" />
</bean>

<!-- A JmsTemplate instance that uses the cached connection and destination -->
<bean id="jmsTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="cachedConnectionFactory" />
    <property name="sessionTransacted" value="true" />
    <property name="pubSubDomain" value="true"/>
</bean>

<bean id="testTopic" class="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQTopic">
    <constructor-arg value="test.topic" />
</bean>

<!-- The Spring message listener container configuration -->
<jms:listener-container destination-type="topic"
    connection-factory="connectionFactory" transaction-manager="transactionManager"
    acknowledge="transacted" concurrency="1">
    <jms:listener destination="test.topic" ref="testReceiver"
        method="receive" />
</jms:listener-container>
```

The producer:

```
@Component("producer")
public class EventProducer {

    @Autowired
    private JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

    @Transactional
    public void produceEvent(String message) {
        this.jmsTemplate.convertAndSend("test.topic", message);
    }
}
```

The consumer:

```
@Component("testReceiver")
public class EventListener {

    @Transactional
    public void receive(String message) {
        System.out.println(message);
    }  
}
```

The test:

```
    @Autowired
    private EventProducer eventProducer;

    public void testMessages() {

    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        this.eventProducer.produceEvent("message" + i);
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

That's the nature of JMS topics - only current subscribers receive messages by default. You have a race condition and are sending messages before the consumer has established its subscription, after the container is started. This is a common mistake with unit/integration tests with topics where you are sending and receiving in the same application.

With newer versions of Spring, there is a [method you can poll to wait until the subscriber is established](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.0.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/listener/DefaultMessageListenerContainer.html#isRegisteredWithDestination--) (since 3.1, I think). Or, you can just wait a little while before starting to send, or you can make your subscriptions durable.

Comment: Hi Gary,
Thank you for your answer, but I'm not sure I understand it.
First of all, we're not using JUnit, this is just a simple scenario we created to check if the configuration works before adding more topics, listeners etc.
Also, the lost messages are not necessarily the first ones we send (So some messages were already received before the lost ones).
We tried adding Thread.sleep(2000) before we start sending, but it didn't solve the problem, and we wouldn't do it in a real scenario anyway...
I'll check out the link you provided and see if it helps. :)

Comment: Also, do you may behave an example of how to configure a durable subscription in the spring xmls?
Thanks!:)

Comment: I changed my answer to remove the reference to JUnit; I meant tests in general where you are sending and receiving in the same app. Make sure the context is fully refreshed and the consumers have started before sending messages. Look at TRACE level logs to watch the consumers start consuming. Durable subscriptions: see clientId, destinationType, and subscription here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jms.html#jms-namespace Bear in mind the subscription won't be durable until the first subscription completes (so your first attempt might fail).